# Firebase SHA1-Certificate is already used by another App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging but I messed something up, so I Deleted the Project and unpacked my Backup.

Now I want to connect my app with Firebase again, but the problem is that it's saying that my SHA1-Certificate is already used by another app (of-course) and now I cannot link my app again.

How do I remove the connection between the SHA1 Certificate and the old App? Also, do I have to wait for 30 days now for the old Project being removed?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the app from the other project where you originally added it with the same package and SHA-1.  There is a "delete this app" button at the bottom of the general setting page that shows all the apps you previously added.

Comment: Thanks Doug. It would be more helpful if you can show a screenshot, since I couldn't find any "delete this app" button in my signing report. :(

Comment: Firebase console -> your project -> Project settings (gear icon) -> Select app -> Delete this app

Comment: Oh yes you mean login to Firebase. I was searching in my AS project.  Thanks so much Doug! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, if i try to Connect to Firebase through Android Studio still says that my SHA1 is already used by another app. Is there a way to get a different SHA1?